# Table with record occurrences count for each column in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, count

I'm looking to generate a table of columns containing count of the occurences of each unique record using PostgreSQL. My current approach is following:

```
with a as (SELECT count(*) as count_each_record_a
FROM (SELECT column1 as word from table_name) t
group by word),

b as (SELECT count(*) as count_each_record_b
FROM (SELECT column2 as word from table_name) t
group by word)

select * from a, b;
```

When I run part of the query, as in:

```
SELECT count(*) as count_each_record_b
FROM (SELECT column2 as word from table_name) t
group by word
```

then I get proper results.

When I run the whole query, I get the proper results for `count_each_record_a`, but column `count_each_record_b` is populated only with `1`. Column `count_each_record_b` should be the same as when running the query by itself.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `select * from a, b` Your select results in a Carthesian product.

Comment: You could try to play with `grouping sets`: `select column1, column2, count(*) from table_name group by grouping sets ((column1),(column2));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually found an answer, even if it's not that straightforward:

```
with a as (SELECT ARRAY(SELECT count(*)
FROM (SELECT a as word from table) t
group by word) as a),
     
b as (SELECT ARRAY (SELECT count(*)
FROM (SELECT b as word from table) t
group by word) as b)
select * from a, b
```

I get for each column one row with an array containing the occurences. Since I'm using this data further, it does serve my needs, but I would't call this a proper solution for the concept problem at hand.